# how to estimate the speed in aerial images

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a project in which I have to calculate the speed of the objects present in aerial images.could anyone suggest an appropriate algorithm or method for the purpose.It would be of great help to me.

Comment: Unless you have dual cameras or some other means of measuring distance to the objects, I'm not sure how it would be possible differentiate between a distant object moving quickly and a closer object moving more slowly.

Answer (score 0):

3D motion tracking is quite involved. I will point you to a couple of references that might help you:
[How can I find the 3D coordinates of a projected rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631039/how-can-i-find-the-3d-coordinates-of-a-projected-rectangle)
http://www.researchgate.net/publication/51956407_The_Object_Projection_Feature_Estimation_Problem_in_UnsupervisedMarkerless_3D_Motion_Tracking